# Python loop list in function call

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

This is my first question on StackOverflow. I have always found what I was looking for just googling, but this time I'm stuck and can't figure it out.

I'm a beginner programmer with python and still learning a lot.

I want to change a dateEdit box in a Userinterface with a small code to set det current date time. 
the code looks like this.

```
self.dateEdit_2.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
```

Now i want to change every dateEdit box the same, starting from 2 and going to 29, without typing every single line out.

i have tried to make a for loop with a filled list.
and i get it to print out what i want, but how does i get "set_date_numb" to be a attribute that does what i want.

hope you understand, Thanks.

```
    dateTimeList = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
    '10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20',
    '21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29']
    indexval = 0
    for i in range(len(dateTimeList)):
        date_numb = (dateTimeList[indexval])
        set_date_numb ='self.dateEdit_{}.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())'.format(date_numb)
        print(set_date_numb)
        indexval += 1
```

Comment: Hey, I saw your earlier answer that said my answer helped you. I'm glad it worked out. If it did work, would you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `getattr()`, see the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). Since the functions you are after are members of your instance you can grab them with their names as strings (which I think is the main problem you are facing):

```
dateTimeList = [str(x) for x in range(2,30)]

for dt in dateTimeList:
    name = "dateEdit_{}".format(dt)
    currentDateEdit = getattr(self, name)
    currentDateEdit.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
```